# Disable database writes in rails console (just for current session)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

When debugging production data, I sometimes will use the Rails console to inspect and query data.

I prefer the Rails (ActiveRecord) console to a raw SQL client.

Is there a way to tell Rails to not write to the DB during my console session to avoid accidentally modifying production data?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably you are looking `rails console --sandbox`

[Rails documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#rails-console)